# Shiny - renderPlot in renderUI - Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm pretty new at this so forgive me - I'm building an app in Shiny that takes an uploaded data file of a fixed format, and renders out various plots based on user selections. One important part of the app is a set of tabs which each contain one plot.

I'm using renderUI to render the tabs but I'm having a bunch of difficulty rendering the plot. I've tried renderPlot, outputPlot and can't get the plot to show. I get various errors but the code below is generating "Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'" at the point where we renderPlot(engPlot).

ui.R

```
# Define UI
shinyUI(fluidPage(
# Application title
  titlePanel("Chart Creation Tool"),
# Sidebar
sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("fileBlob", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL),
      selectInput("selectAnalysis", label=h3("Select Input"), choices=c("Month x Year", "Strategies", "Programs", "Segments")),
   uiOutput("strategyList")
),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  uiOutput("mainPanel")      
)
)
))
```

mainPanel portion of server.R

```
output$mainPanel <- renderUI ({

if (length(RawImport())==0L) {

  out <- NULL

}else{
  if (input$selectAnalysis=="Month x Year") {
    dfAggMonth <- aggregate(cbind(Sent,Delivered,UniqueOpens,Responders,Bounced,Unsubscribes,TotalSpamComplaints,HardBounces,SoftBounces) ~ SentMonth + SentYear + SentMonthName, RawImport(), FUN = sum)
    dfAggMonth <- addRatios(dfAggMonth)
    dfAggMonth <- dfAggMonth[with(dfAggMonth, order(Date)), ]

    engPlot <- runplot(paste(dfAggMonth$SentMonthName, dfAggMonth$SentYear,sep="-"), dfAggMonth$Date, dfAggMonth$Delivered, dfAggMonth$UniqueOpenRate, dfAggMonth$ResponderRate, "engagement", , "Temp Title")

    out <- tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Engagement", "Engagement", renderPlot(engPlot)), 
      tabPanel("Summary", "summary", "summary"),
      tabPanel("Deliverability",runplot(paste(dfAggMonth$SentMonthName, dfAggMonth$SentYear,sep="-"), dfAggMonth$Date, dfAggMonth$Delivered, dfAggMonth$BounceRate, , "deliverability", , "Temp Title"))
      )  
  }
  else {
    out <- tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1", input$selectAnalysis), 
      tabPanel("Tab 2", input$selectAnalysis)
    )
  }

}

out
})
```

RunPlot Function

```
runplot <- function(xSeriesLabels, xSeriesValues, leftseries, rightseries1, rightseries2, chartType, columnSeries, xTitle){

if (missing(xTitle)==FALSE) {
   strTitle <- xTitle
  } else {
    strTitle <- "no title supplied"
  }


  p <- barplot(leftseries, width=1, col=barCol, axisnames = leftseries, names.arg=xSeriesLabels, axis.lty=1, xlab=strTitle)

  return(p)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found this error often occurs when you're running a function that's meant to be run in `server.R` in `ui.R`.

So you'll have to remember that `renderUI` is going to create a full-fledged client-side UI. That means that any code you're returning in your dynamic UI (even though it happens to be stored in `server.R` must really be valid client-side code that could exist in `ui.R`. That also means that testing can be much easier in that you can just move the code you're trying to create dynamically (such as one of the `out` tabsetPanels) to your `ui.R` to see if it works. That may make debugging easier in the future.

In this case, I think the problem you'd see if you did that is around the `renderPlot` call. Since you're just creating a dynamic UI here, you want to use the UI-compatible functions, which is `plotOutput("plotName")`, in this case. Then on the server side you'll assign a plot to that output.

```
output$plotName <- renderPlot({
 ...
})
```

Which will do what you want when the plot is visible, and will have no visible effect when the plot isn't shown.